# wxpython wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN

Tags: wxpython

hey this is a general wxpython mouseevent question..
if in my wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN handler and i suppose any other mouse event in wx if i dont call event.Skip() the window goes buggy and my clicks dont register to other widgets. is event.Skip() a must for every mouse event in wx?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, event.Skip() isn't required.  The point of it is to allow parents to also receive the event.  If you want the parents to receive the event, use event.Skip(), if you don't, then don't use it; it depends on the application.  See [this link](http://wiki.wxpython.org/EventPropagation).

One thing to keep in mind (for the generalization of this question) is that event propagation is different for wx.Event and a wx.CommandEvent.  See [this link](http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind) for more.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.. ok after reading that it makes more sense. thanks tom :)